# How to go to a page, click a button and then get it's DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a script in javascript/jquery that once executed must go a sub-page, click on a button and then get the DOM of that resulting page. After which I can just do some manipulation and get some needed data.

After some digging around I wrote this script:

```
var pageDOM = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
xhr.open('GET', '/newsfeed-simulator', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4)  { 
      pageDOM = xhr.responseXML;
      pageDOM.getElementById("simulate-button").click();
  }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

With this script, I can access the required sub-page but xhr.responseXML always returns null. I googled and added `xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml');` but it still doesn't work. The weird thing is that `xhr.responseText;` works fine.

Not sure whats wrong, it should be a straight forward task? Any ideas/comments/suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Best,

P.S.: It's first post here, so hi :D

**EDIT1** newsfeed-simulator is basically a page with a button that I need to click. Once clicked the page is loaded with elements, which then I can use to get some data.

**EDIT2** After a few hours of googling I came up with this

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/newsfeed-simulator', true);
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    console.log(xhr.response)
    xhr.response.getElementById("simulate-button").click();
    console.log(xhr.response.body)
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

Using XMLHttpRequest2 I can now get the source easily (as a document and not a text) and not get a null. Problem is (as charlietfl hinted) `xhr.response.getElementById("simulate-button").click();`is not working correctly. I.E. I am getting the body of the DOM without the button being clicked on.
Any ideas how can I simulate a mouseClick, cuz my way is not working?

Comment: your click concept won't work regardless. You will have to parse the url you want from the xml and redirect using `window.location`

Comment: Can you post what newsfeed-simulator returns?

Comment: @charlietfl, can you further expand on your answer please? I am a newbie to javascript, just started programming in this language a few hours ago :)

Comment: @lmortenson newsfeed-simulator returns a simulated newsfeed. Basically a big text of HTML that I need to parse to get some data. I must simulate a few clicks before all that though. Will edit my original post accordingly.

Comment: show sample of xml that contains button you want. There will be no script assigned to that button the way there would be if it was loaded in another page, so you need to pull the url wanted from the xml

Comment: All I have to go by is this: <a id="simulate-button" class="link">Simulate feed</a>. To clarify the button just loads elements into the page, it does not redirect you to another page.